# Does the `nodes()` method keep the document order?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Does the `nodes()` method of the `xml` data type return nodes in document order?

For example, if there are data like:

```sql
declare @xml xml;
set @xml = '<Fruits><Apple /><Banana /><Orange /><Pear /></Fruits>';
```

which is queried as

```sql
select T.c.query('.')
from @xml.nodes('/Fruits/*') T(c);
```

will elements be returned in document order? Order of rows returned by `select` is known to be undefined if `order by` clause is omitted. Is it the case for `select ... from ... .nodes()`, or is it exceptional?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, `nodes()` generates a row set in document order. The operator used in the query plan to do this is the [Table Valued Function XML Reader](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190769%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

> Table-valued Function XML Reader inputs an XML BLOB as a parameter and
>   produces a row set representing XML nodes in XML document order. Other
>   input parameters may restrict XML nodes returned to a subset of XML
>   document.

But a query without `order by` has an undefined order so there are no guarantees.

One way to work around that is to use the `id` generated by the table valued function in `row_number() over()` clause and use the generated number in the order by.

```sql
select X.q
from
  (
  select T.c.query('.') as q,
         row_number() over(order by T.c) as rn
  from @xml.nodes('/Fruits/*') T(c)
  ) as X
order by X.rn
```

It is not possible to use `T.c` in an `order by` directly. Trying that will give you

> Msg 493, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   
> The column 'c' that was returned from the nodes() method cannot be used directly. It can only be used with one of the four XML data type methods, exist(), nodes(), query(), and value(), or in IS NULL and IS NOT NULL checks.

The error did not mention that it should work with `row_number` but it does and that could  very well be bug that might get fixed so the code above will fail. But up until SQL Server 2012 it works just fine.

A way to get a guaranteed order without relying on the undocumented use of `row_number` would be to use a table of numbers where you extract the nodes by position.

```sql
select T.c.query('.') as q
from Numbers as N
  cross apply @xml.nodes('/Fruits/*[sql:column("N.Number")]') as T(c)
where N.Number between 1 and @xml.value('count(/Fruits/*)', 'int')
order by N.Number
```

Comment: While I upvoted this post (because it contains the best collection of information I've seen on the topic), this a definite hole in Microsoft's SQL implementation.  Oracle, DB2 and PostgreSQL (at a minimum) have FOR ORDINALITY columns in XMLTables.  I find some things easier using T-SQL's (non-ANSI) XML extensions; other things are easier with ANSI-style SQL/XML.  Mostly it's a wash.  But this is a conspicuously missing feature with no clean alternative (he said, hoping MS was listening).