# Advanced Find/Replace Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

Say I have over 200 of these,

> (17, 'BH', 'BAHRAIN', 'Bahrain', 'BHR', 48, 973),

Is there a way I to remove, everything except `'Bahrain' and 973,`
besides going through them one by one?

Comment: Do you want to keep both cases of Bahrain?

Comment: Is it always bahrain and 973 in the 200 cases, or is this more a "keep data at position 4 and 7" problem?

Comment: @Bohemian, No just Titlecase Bahrain.

Comment: @kl78,No its different country and areacodes, so it will be keep data in position 4 and 7.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449492/using-t-sql-return-nth-delimited-element-from-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capturing groups

```
Find What: \(.*,.*,.*,(.*),.*,.*,(.*)\)

Replace With: (\1,\2)
```

Comment: Thanks, what will (\1,\2) do?

Comment: \1 is the first capturing group (4th position) and \2 is the second capturing group (7th position). Each capturing group appears in regular expression in parentheses