# SQL SERVER select string from right after a certain character

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a bit of problem regarding sql select statement.
I have a column value that look like this

```
    2>4>5 or
    28>30>52 or
    300>410>500 or
    2>4>5>8
```

My question is, how can i get the value from **RIGHT** after the >
character,  so the select statement from the value above will return

```
    4
    30
    410
    5
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: from where comes `400` ?

Comment: Your third row doesn't contain 400, just 410. Do you want the second number or the second to last (as the fourth example may show)? Please update the question to reflect your answer, and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Also your column contains multiple `>` characters. after which  `>` character do you need get value ?

Comment: Sorry,it should return 410. I just want to get the second value from right of the string after the > character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `second value from right`, then try:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, '>', -2), '>', 1);
```

**EDIT**

One solution for sql server:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(max);
set @str = '2>4>5>8';

SELECT reverse( substring(
    substring( reverse(@str),  charindex( '>', reverse(@str) )+1, len(@str)  ),  0, 
    charindex( '>', substring( reverse(@str),  charindex( '>', reverse(@str) )+1, len(@str)  ) ) 
    ) );
```

Comment: Im using a sql server 2014, when i execute the query it returns SUBSTRING_INDEX is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Then why you tagged your question as mysql ?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to extracting the n-th element from a delimited string. The only difference is that in this case we want the n-th-to-last element. The change can be achieved with a double use of `reverse`. Assuming the table is `MyTable` and the field is `MyColumn`, here's one way:

```
SELECT
    Reverse(
        CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(Reverse(MyColumn),'>','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]', --x[2] because it's the second element in the reversed string
        'varchar(5)' --Use something long enough to catch any number which might occur here
        ))
FROM
    MyTable
```

With credit to @Shnugo for his efforts here: [Using T-SQL, return nth delimited element from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449492/using-t-sql-return-nth-delimited-element-from-a-string)

You can't cast as an `int` where I've put `varchar(5)`since at that stage the strings are still reversed. If you need to convert to an integer, do that by wrapping a convert/cast on the outside.

Comment: This is exactly what i need, thank you so much Steve.You saved me a lot of time..

Comment: upvote, huh, SQL server have so poor functionality for working with strings

Comment: Yep @OtoShavadze, some things are much easier in MySQL. Not everything though. There are no Window Functions for example. I think it's because MySQL is so tied to web-technologies that it tends to have different drivers for the functionality.

Comment: `some things are much easier in MySQL`, also if comparing to another DB's, for example regex support is missing here, sometimes this is serious drawback, when working with strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte1(Value)
AS
(
SELECT  '2>4>5'      Union all
SELECT  '28>30>52'     Union all
SELECT  '300>410>500'  Union all
SELECT  '2>4>5>8' 
)
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(
(
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(((REVERSE((SUBSTRING(Value, RIGHT(CHARINDEX('>', Value), Len(Value)) + 1, Len(Value)))))),
CHARINDEX('>',((REVERSE((SUBSTRING(Value, RIGHT(CHARINDEX('>', Value), Len(Value)) + 1, Len(Value)))))))+1,LEN(Value)))
),CHARINDEX('>',(
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(((REVERSE((SUBSTRING(Value, RIGHT(CHARINDEX('>', Value), Len(Value)) + 1, Len(Value)))))),
CHARINDEX('>',((REVERSE((SUBSTRING(Value, RIGHT(CHARINDEX('>', Value), Len(Value)) + 1, Len(Value)))))))+1,LEN(Value)))
))+1,LEN(Value))

 AS ExpectedValue
FROM cte1
```