# SQL Split Row Data Separated by Spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, substring, sql-server-2016

I am looking for a query
to find nth value in a list.  The separator is anything greater than or equal to 2 spaces. (it can be 3, or 5 spaces).
Trying to avoid scalar value functions, since performance may be slower. The sentences can have any number of words, from 5-20.

```
create table dbo.TestWrite (TestWriteId int primary key identity(1,1), TextRow varchar(255))
insert into dbo.TestWrite (TextRow)

I    am    writing       SQL  Code.                          -- Row 1: Column 1: I ,    Column 2: am,       Column 3: writing...
SQL   keywords    include       join,   except,      where.  -- Row 2: Column 1: SQL,   Column 2: keywords, Column 3: include...
```

Would like in individual rows with columns, see expected output -- comments above, using a select statement.

This maybe one solution trying to utilize.
[Using T-SQL, return nth delimited element from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449492/using-t-sql-return-nth-delimited-element-from-a-string)

```
DECLARE @dlmt NVARCHAR(10)=N' ';
DECLARE @pos INT = 2;
SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@input,@dlmt,N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[sql:variable("@pos")][1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: @DarkRob, the expected output is in the comments beside the row data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the fact, that splitting the string by blanks leads to a lot of empty elements. Picking the *2nd fragment* has a high chance to hit such an empty one.

There are two approaches:

1. Remove all multiple spaces to return your strings with on single blank as delimiter. Then use the approach you've found in the other question.
2. Use `XQuery` to return only elements with a `text()` node.

Try this out:

```
DECLARE @TestWrite TABLE(TestWriteId int primary key identity(1,1), TextRow varchar(255))
insert into @TestWrite (TextRow) values
 ('I    am    writing       SQL  Code.')                           -- Row 1: Column 1: I ,    Column 2: am,       Column 3: writing...
,('SQL   keywords    include       join,   except,      where.');  -- Row 2: Column 1: SQL,   Column 2: keywords, Column 3: include...
```

ad 1. : Use any two characters, which will not appear in your strings

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TextRow,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')
FROM @TestWrite;
```

ad 2.

```
DECLARE @dlmt NVARCHAR(10)=N' ';
DECLARE @pos INT = 2;

SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(t.TextRow,@dlmt,N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML)
      .query('/x[text()]')  --<-- Here's the magic
      .value('/x[sql:variable("@pos")][1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @TestWrite t
```