# How to split string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a string like "How are you john?". I need to split the string based on user input index. The problem is words need not to split.

Example:

- Input Query : How are you john?
- Split Index : 5

I am getting output like this:

```
How are you john?
```

Expected output:

```
How
are 
you 
john?
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Ideally, do string processing in a *general purpose programming language* with good string manipulation facilities. Not T-SQL. As it is, I've got no idea *what* the relevance of "Split Index : 5" is - you don't seem to use it anywhere else in the question and the two answers posted so far seem to ignore it also.

Comment: @Gowdham check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very good function **[STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM STRING_SPLIT ('How are you john?', ' ') AS cs;
```

This will give you desired output.

Second parameter can be anything you like e.g. ',' or '\'

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a08f9/2/0)

Comment: Worth to mention, that `STRING_SPLIT()` will need v2016+ and that the result is not guaranteed to be returned in the given order. Quite a draw back... There is a [workaround calling `OPENJSON`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38275075/5089204) (needs v2016+ as well). And there are several approaches for versions below v2016

Comment: @Shnugo yes you are right that is why I added link to documentation. Do you know when order will be different? I have never had a case.

Comment: Well - uhm - no ;-) The point is: It is not guaranteed. The only fact guaranteed is: The **sorting of a resultset is random without an explicit `ORDER BY` on the outermost query**. In fact I'm pretty sure, that this will work in most cases. But (if you return a larger set), the engine might decide to work this down in parallel. Or if the egine decides to re-sort your set to perform a join operation, this might be changed...

Comment: @Shnugo well I think it is caused by fact that any result-set returned by SELECT (without ORDER BY clause) theoretically doesn't have guaranteed order and may be different in different conditions. Since here we also get result-set it behaves similarly ... in theory :)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point: We know **for sure**, that the result set **can** be in any order. Very often we use an approach in various places. Just imagine, you find this reliably working in all tested cases and then create a VIEW or an iTVF using this and you call this in another query. Later steps migth mess it up... I'd just not rely on something potentially random...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
Create Table tblData (inputString Varchar(50));    
Insert Into tblData Values('How are you john?')

SELECT   
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT   
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([inputString], ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  tblData) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Comment: This is dangerous, if your string could include forbidden characters. You might [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274439/5089204) to find an enhancement. As an alternative you can wrap the text in a `CDATA` section.

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks I will check it later.