# Script to get all numbers between Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to find a way to get the numbers between the dashes. This is the only way I know to do it, but I know that not all of our accounts are the same length. So I am just looking for a way to get everything between before, after and between the dashes. This is an example of the types of accounts we have. '2-0-200-325-0' and '1-0-1105-1500-1520' The non-digit characters are only dashes and nothing else.
[image]

```
 declare @Department Int
 declare @Account Int
 declare @Company Int
 declare @Location Int
 declare @SubAccount Int
 declare @AccountNo varchar(24) = '2-0-200-325-0'
 declare @CommaPos Int

 select @CommaPos = charindex('-',@accountno)

 set @Company = substring(@accountno,1,@CommaPos-1)
 select @Company as Company

 set @Location = Substring(@AccountNo, @CommaPos+1, 1)
 select @Location as Location

 set @Department = Substring(@AccountNo, @CommaPos+3, 4)
 select @Department as Department

 set @Account = Substring(@AccountNo, @CommaPos+8, 4)
 select @Account as Account

 set @SubAccount = Substring(@AccountNo, @CommaPos+13, 4)
 select @SubAccount as SubAccount
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you use and its version. And explain if the possible non-digit characters are only dashes or if something else is also possible and what these characters are.

Comment: What you write above here is not SQL, but, very probably, the SQL Server procedural language. Can you show a table with a few rows that you want to treat? And, yes, confirm the SQL flavour, the DBMS you use?

Comment: The edit reveals that your schema isn't normalized. The proper way to solve this is to normalize the schema and store each number (one for the company, one for the location, one for the account and so on) in one column of it's one. Read ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad?r=SearchResults&s=1|192.8353).

Comment: This is from a Vendor system we are implementing and not "our" tables so I cannot change the table structure. We will be using this table to push information into our accounting system though, which is why i need to separate the numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option uses a recursive query for parsing. This properly handles the variable lenght of each part - and can easily be extended to handle more parts if needed.

```
-- declare the variables
declare @AccountNo varchar(24) = '2-0-200-325-0';
declare @Department Int;
declare @Account Int;
declare @Company Int;
declare @Location Int;
declare @SubAccount Int;

-- parse and assign values to variables
with cte as (
    select 
        substring(@AccountNo + '-', 1, charindex('-', @AccountNo + '-') - 1) val,
        substring(@AccountNo + '-', charindex('-', @AccountNo + '-') + 1, len(@AccountNo)) rest,
        1 lvl
    union all
    select
        substring(rest, 1, charindex('-', rest) - 1),
        substring(rest, charindex('-', rest) + 1, len(rest)),
        lvl + 1
    from cte
    where charindex('-', rest) > 0
)
select 
    @Company = max(case when lvl = 1 then val end),
    @Location = max(case when lvl = 2 then val end),
    @Department = max(case when lvl = 3 then val end),
    @Account = max(case when lvl = 4 then val end),
    @SubAccount = max(case when lvl = 5 then val end)
from cte;

-- check the results
select 
    @AccountNo AccountNo, 
    @Company Company, 
    @Location Location, 
    @Department Department, 
    @Account Account, 
    @SubAccount SubAccount
;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb119e97db79634ad8b4e8406efec5da)**:

```
AccountNo     | Company | Location | Department | Account | SubAccount
:------------ | ------: | -------: | ---------: | ------: | ---------:
2-0-200-325-0 |       2 |        0 |        200 |     325 |          0
```

Comment: I think that a recursive approach with conditional aggregation is rather expensive here...

Answer (score 0):

This was my approach:

--first I use a declared table variable to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,ACCOUNT_NO VARCHAR(24))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('2-0-200-325-0');
```

--The query

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.ACCOUNT_NO
      ,casted.value('x[1]','int') AS Company
      ,casted.value('x[2]','int') AS Location
      ,casted.value('x[3]','int') AS Department
      ,casted.value('x[4]','int') AS Account
      ,casted.value('x[5]','int') AS SubAccount
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t.ACCOUNT_NO,'-','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML))) A(casted);
```

The idea in short:

- We use simple string operations to transform your dash-separated list of numbers into XML.
- Now we can use XQuery to retrieve each element by its position (typesafe!).

Find [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274439/5089204). In this link there is also a faster approach using JSON support (needs v2016+):

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.ACCOUNT_NO
      ,A.*
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[[',REPLACE(t.ACCOUNT_NO,'-',','),']]'))
            WITH(Company    INT '$[0]'
                ,Location   INT '$[1]'
                ,Department INT '$[2]'
                ,Account    INT '$[3]'
                ,SubAccount INT '$[4]') A;
```

The idea of this JSON approach:

- Agains we use some simple string operations to transform your string into a JSON array.
- Using two array brackets (`[[`) allows to use `OPENJSON()` with a `WITH` clause.
- The `WITH` clause allows to grab each fragment by its (zero-based) position (typesafe).
- The `WITH` clause is some kind of *implicit pivoting*.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
    --  First Create this function. This is what you need.
    --  It will split a sentence into words, given a defined separator

        CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_SplitString] (@Sentence varchar(max), @Separator char(1))
                RETURNS @WordList TABLE (Word varchar(50)) 
            AS
                BEGIN
                    SET @Separator  =   ISNULL(@Separator, ' ') 
                    DECLARE @Word   varchar(50)
                    SET @Sentence = LTRIM(@Sentence) + @Separator   
                    WHILE   (CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Sentence) > 0)
                        BEGIN
                            SET @Word = SUBSTRING(@Sentence, 1, CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Sentence) - 1)
                            INSERT INTO @WordList   SELECT LTRIM(@Word)
                            -- Remove word added to the List from the sentence.
                            SET @Sentence =  SUBSTRING(@Sentence,   CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Sentence) + 1,   LEN(@Sentence))
                            SET @Sentence =  LTRIM(@Sentence)           
                    END                 
                    RETURN
                END 
        GO
*/

DECLARE     @AccountList    TABLE   (AccountNo varchar(20), Variable varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @AccountList    VALUES
            ('1-0-1105-1200-1290','')
        ,   ('1-0-1105-1500-1520','')
        ,   ('1-0-1105-1500-1620','')
        ,   ('1-0-1106-1200-1250','')
        ,   ('1-0-1106-1200-1290','')
        ,   ('1-0-1106-1500-1520','')
;

DECLARE     @VariableList       TABLE   (OrderNo int, VariableName varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @VariableList       VALUES
            (1, 'Company    ')
        ,   (2, 'Location   ')
        ,   (3, 'Department ')
        ,   (4, 'Account    ')
        ,   (5, 'SubAccount ')
;

SELECT
        AccountNo
    ,   Variable    =   (SELECT VariableName FROM @VariableList WHERE RowNo = OrderNo)
    ,   Value       =   Word
FROM    (   
            SELECT  
                    RowNo       =   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNo ORDER BY AccountNo)
                ,   AccountNo   =   L.AccountNo
                ,   Variable    =   ''
                ,   Word        =   W.Word

            FROM        @AccountList                            L
            CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_SplitString(L.AccountNo, '-')   W   -- Here how to use the function

        )   R
```

Comment: A multi-line tvf together with a while loop was okay about 20 years ago...

Comment: Btw: This is not a recommended approach, but - if you want to stick with this - you should add an identity column to ensure the expected sort order. With larger strings your tvf might mix this up...