# Can using multiple JSON_VALUE-s in MSSQL query harm performance

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, database, select

I have table in sql server database which have column of json type.

```
Table - SomeTable
Id | Properties
1  | {"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2", "field3":"value3", "field4":"value4"}
2  | {"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2", "field3":"value3", "field4":"value4"}
...|...
```

I wrote select query which selects value of each field separately:

```
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$.field1') as field1,
    JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$.field2') as field2,
    JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$.field3') as field3,
    JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$.field4') as field4
FROM SomeTable
```

I found this approach in Microsoft's docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Can writing many JSON_VALUE-s in query harm performance ? Is SQL doing deserialization of string for each JSON_VALUE written in query.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "yes".  But it is easy enough to check by timing simple queries (on enough data) with different numbers of references.

Comment: Is there better way for getting json fields separately using sql server ?

Comment: Using `OPENJSON` would likely be better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You  may try to use `OPENJSON()` with an explicit schema to parse the JSON stored in the `Properties` column with one function call (against four or more `JSON_VALUE()` calls):

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (
   Id int,
   Properties varchar(1000)
)
INSERT INTO SomeTable (Id, Properties)
VALUES
   (1, '{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2", "field3":"value3", "field4":"value4"}'),
   (2, '{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2", "field3":"value3", "field4":"value4"}')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT s.Id, j.*
FROM SomeTable s
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(s.Properties) WITH (
   field1 varchar(100) '$.field1',
   field2 varchar(100) '$.field2',
   field3 varchar(100) '$.field3',
   field4 varchar(100) '$.field4'
) j
```

Result:

```
Id  field1  field2  field3  field4
----------------------------------
1   value1  value2  value3  value4
2   value1  value2  value3  value4
```

As an additional note, the result from the `JSON_VALUE()` is a scalar value of type `nvarchar(4000)`. With `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema you may define the appropriate data type for the returned columns.

Comment: That is It ! Thanks for response

Comment: @TigranPetrosyan, OPENJSON is better if you want to select multiple columns. See the performance comparison done in the SO link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62506490/t-sql-to-get-the-5th-word-in-each-row-in-a-database/62508469#62508469

Answer (score 6):

I thought I would do a test in regards to your question:

> Can writing many JSON_VALUE-s in query harm performance ? Is SQL doing deserialization of string for each JSON_VALUE written in query.

So I create the below script and tested on my home work station:

```sql
/*
Id | Properties
1  | {"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2", "field3":"value3", "field4":"value4"}
2  | {"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2", "field3":"value3", "field4":"value4"}
*/

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int IDENTITY,
                            Properties nvarchar(4000));

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6)
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (Properties)
SELECT N'{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2", "field3":"value3", "field4":"value4"}'
FROM Tally;
GO

DECLARE @StartTime datetime2(7) = SYSDATETIME();

SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$.field1') as field1,
    JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$.field2') as field2,
    JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$.field3') as field3,
    JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$.field4') as field4
FROM dbo.YourTable;

PRINT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@StartTime, SYSDATETIME());

SET @StartTime = SYSDATETIME();

SELECT YT.Id,
       OJ.field1,
       OJ.field2,
       OJ.field3,
       OJ.field4
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(YT.Properties)
                 WITH(field1 varchar(50),
                      field2 varchar(50),
                      field3 varchar(50),
                      field4 varchar(50)) OJ;

PRINT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@StartTime, SYSDATETIME());

GO 10

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable
```

This uses your solution, with `JSON_VALUE` and also an `OPENJSON` solution (which I'd written around the same time as Zhorov posted his answer). On my workstation, this resulted in the below output from the messages:

```
(1000000 rows affected)
5273
(1000000 rows affected)
3560
(1000000 rows affected)
5196
(1000000 rows affected)
3329
(1000000 rows affected)
5097
(1000000 rows affected)
3320
(1000000 rows affected)
5219
(1000000 rows affected)
3379
(1000000 rows affected)
5133
(1000000 rows affected)
3239
(1000000 rows affected)
5137
(1000000 rows affected)
3352
(1000000 rows affected)
5080
(1000000 rows affected)
3348
(1000000 rows affected)
5126
(1000000 rows affected)
3320
(1000000 rows affected)
5146
(1000000 rows affected)
3360
(1000000 rows affected)
5310
(1000000 rows affected)
3354
```

Notice that the second row, with `OPENJSON`, is about 2 second faster for every run. This is, however, with 1,000,000 million rows, but it does confirm that a single parse of the JSON is far faster than 4.