# Extract values from JSON of Array in T-SQL

Tags: arrays, json, t-sql

I have a JSON like this to process in SQL

`{"RowIndex":[1,2], "Data":["a","b"]}`

and i want to extract the data to show that as a table like this

```
RowIndex    Data
  1           a
  2           b
```

I understand that i have to use OPENJSON, JSON_QUERY or JSON_VALUE but i cannot find a way to get what I want that not implies to write a query with many join like

```
select  C1.value as RowIndex,
        C2.value as Data,
From (select [key], value from OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@jsonstring, '$.RowIndex'))) C1 
inner join (select [key], value from OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@jsonstring, '$.Data'))) C2 on C1.[key] = C2.[key]
```

Because if the arrays in the JSON grow the query will be unmaintenable and slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method, using a "couple" of `OPENJSON` clauses:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{"RowIndex":[1,2], "Data":["a","b"]}';

SELECT RI.[value] AS RowIndex,
       D.[value] AS Data
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
     WITH (RowIndex nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON,
           Data nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) J
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(RowIndex) RI
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Data) D
WHERE RI.[key] = D.[key];
```

To elaborate on my comments though, it seems like you should be fixing the JSON design and have something like this:

```
[
    {
        "RowIndex": "1",
        "Data": "a",
        "Number": "1"
    },
    {
        "RowIndex": "2",
        "Data": "b",
        "Number": "3"
    }
]
```

Which can be far more easily queried:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'[
    {
        "RowIndex": "1",
        "Data": "a",
        "Number": "1"
    },
    {
        "RowIndex": "2",
        "Data": "b",
        "Number": "3"
    }
]';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
     WITH (RowIndex int,
           Data char(1),
           Number int) OJ;
```

Comment: If I understand well, if I have 3 arrays there will be 3 OPENJSON and so on

Comment: Correct, @MattiaGiacone , and more clauses in your `WHERE`. If that is the case, however, then it seems the real problem is the JSON and your JSON should look more like this (added an extra node, `Number`): `[{"RowIndex": "1","Data": "a","Number":"1"},{"RowIndex": "2","Data": "b","Number":"3"}]`

Comment: It will be better if I can generate the JSON like `{[{ "RowIndex":0, "Data":"a" },{ "RowIndex":1, "Data":"b" }]}`  to perform a query like `SELECT 
  JSON_VALUE([value], '$.RowIndex') AS RowIndex,
   JSON_VALUE([value], '$.Data') AS Data,
FROM (SELECT [key],[value],[type] FROM OPENJSON(@jsonstring) )`

Comment: Why "spam" `JSON_VALUE` @MattiaGiacone? It's slower (I confirmed this earlier today in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63154238/2029983)).

Comment: yes that's better. The real Json has 12 array and for 250 element with the 12 cross apply it takes around 1 second. But if i create the json in the other way the query is almost instantaneous

Comment: I've updated my answer for if you improve your JSON, @MattiaGiacone .