# Extracting value in between two of the same characters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a nvarchar column that is a file path. For example, the values look like the following:

```
/Example Folder/Example Subfolder/ Example File
```

I want to pull out the first directory name (so for this example, I just want:

```
Example Folder
```

Any suggestions on how to best extract this in SSMS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using T-SQL, return nth delimited element from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449492/using-t-sql-return-nth-delimited-element-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

```
Declare @ColumnName nvarchar(300);
Set @ColumnName = '/Example Folder/Example Subfolder/ Example File'

Select SUBSTRING(@ColumnName,2,CHARINDEX('/',@ColumnName,2)-2) as [First Directory Name]
```

Output:

```
First Directory Name
----------------------
Example Folder
```

To suit it to your needs, replace `@ColumnName` with the ColumnName from the table and add  `from tableName` to the `select` query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(columnname, 0 , CHARINDEX('/',columnname,2))
FROM tableName
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d721ff012a5b1e983d58b14cc3c109ef)*

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following generic method.

It is using XML and XQuery to tokenize a string.
XML/XQuery data model is based on ***ordered sequences***. Exactly what we need for the task.

Both separator and token's position are parameterized. So, it is very easy to retrieve any token in any position.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl(tokens) VALUES 
('/Example Folder/Example Subfolder/Example File'),
('/SampleFolder/SampleSubfolder/SampleFile');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '/'
   , @position INT = 1;

SELECT *
    , c.value('(/root/r[text()][sql:variable("@position")]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(256)') AS token
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| ID |                     tokens                     |     token      |
+----+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|  1 | /Example Folder/Example Subfolder/Example File | Example Folder |
|  2 | /SampleFolder/SampleSubfolder/SampleFile       | SampleFolder   |
+----+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(folder, CHARINDEX('/', folder, 2)), '/', '')
```