# Data Cleaning in SQL Server (SSMS) using SUBSTRING

Tags: sql-server, data-cleaning

I have a particular column that needed a cleaning called Owner Address with a table name NashvilleHousing. Below is the example data of the column;

```
OwnerAddress
-------------
2935  LOUISE DR, NASHVILLE, TN
3019  LOUISE DR, NASHVILLE, TN
3019  LOUISE DR, NASHVILLE, TN
```

I want to extract NASHVILLE only for every record. My query is as such;

```sql
SELECT
SUBSTRING(OwnerAddress, CHARINDEX(',', OwnerAddress)+1, Len(OwnerAddress) - 4)
FROM NashvilleHousing
```

Where did I go wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Is Nashville (or more specifically the town) *always* the 2nd delimited item?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using T-SQL, return nth delimited element from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449492/using-t-sql-return-nth-delimited-element-from-a-string)

Comment: No Larnu, I have recorded OwnerAddress like this as well;

321  MORTON AVE, NASHVILLE

For this case I extract NASHVILLE using this query,

SELECT

SUBSTRING(OwnerAddress, CHARINDEX(',', OwnerAddress)+1, LEN(OwnerAddress))

FROM NashvilleHousing

WHERE OwnerAddress

NOT LIKE '%TN'

Comment: `CASE WHEN OwnerAddress LIKE '%NASHVILLE%' THEN 'NASHVILLE' END`? You are not being clear here.

Comment: Oh yes it works. But I have cities beside NASHVILLE as well in my record such as 112 VINE  LN, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN. I need to extract GOODLETTSVILLE city too. Sorry for not being particular.

Comment: So back to my original question, *"Is Nashville (or more specifically the town) always the 2nd delimited item?"*...

Comment: Yes, the town is always the 2nd delimited item.

Comment: I hope that part of your exercise here is to fix this design. You have violated 1NF by storing multiple values in a single tuple.