# Splitting column value by '\' in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have some data in `FileFullPath` Column

```
Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\Oracle\2022-05-04\MSudaitemlov_20220503
Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\OracleABC\2022-05-04\FDERDMSudaitemlov_20220503
Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\OCSBAGF\2022-05-04\AASSSMSudaitemlov_20220503
```

The part I wanted is:

```
Oracle
OracleABC
OCSBAGF
```

The letters are `dynamic` so, I couldn't apply `Left,Right` function since the length is different. I tried to split it using `'\'` by using `STRING_SPLIT()` but it's saying:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 18
'string_split' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using then? If `STRING_SPLIT` isn't recognised, then you are using SQL Server 2014 or prior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using T-SQL, return nth delimited element from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449492/using-t-sql-return-nth-delimited-element-from-a-string)

Comment: it's version is 18.9.1

Comment: SQL Server 18.9.1 doesn't exist; the latest version of SQL Server is 15.0.4223.1, which is SQL Server 2019 CU 16.

Comment: it's Microsoft SQL server 2016

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` was added in SQL Server 2016, so you should be able to use it. Though, in truth wouldn't help you as it doesn't provide the ordinal position. Though I've linked you to a question on how you can get the nth value.

Comment: I am not able to visualize the refrence you posted @Larnu

Comment: It's splitting in different rows but i need only the extracted part for each of the rows

Comment: So how do you know what part you need? And, more importantly, how does SQL Server know?

Comment: If we look for a pattern, is there one? Looking from the end backwords, does the string always have name, date, and then the string value you want? If you reverse the string, you can split it with a function that provides position and then just grab the third piece. And string splitting is THE MOST COMMON question - lots of functions have been posted that work in every version of sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `STRING_SPLIT()` in SQL Server 2016, except in two scenarios:

1. If you're not calling the function correctly - many people try to call it like a scalar function (`SELECT STRING_SPLIT(...`) instead of a table-valued function (`SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(...`). It returns a table, so you must treat it like a table.
2. If your database's compatibility level is lower than 130. This is called out [at the very top of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql), and I've given several workarounds in [this tip](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6390/sql-server-split-string-replacement-code-with-stringsplit/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) in cases where you can't change compat level.

#### But `STRING_SPLIT()` won't solve this problem anyway...

...because the output order is not guaranteed, so you could never reliably determine which element is 3rd from last.

Borrowing shamelessly from my work in [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7034/sql-split-string-with-openjson/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), you can create the following simple function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitOrdered_JSON
(
  @List      nvarchar(4000),
  @Delimiter nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS table WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN
  (
    SELECT [key], value FROM OPENJSON
    (
      CONCAT
      (
        N'["',
        REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(@List, 'JSON'), 
          @Delimiter, N'","'),
        N'"]')
      ) AS x
    );
```

Then if you're after the 3rd-last element in the string, you can just reverse before parsing, and then reverse again after parsing. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE #f(ID int, FullFilePath nvarchar(4000));

INSERT #f VALUES
(1,N'Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\Oracle\2022-05-04\MSudaitemlov_20220503'),
(2,N'Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\OracleABC\2022-05-04\FDERDMSudaitemlov_20220503'),
(3,N'Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\OCSBAGF\2022-05-04\AASSSMSudaitemlov_20220503');

DECLARE @ElementOfInterest int = 3;

SELECT REVERSE(value) 
  FROM #f CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitOrdered_JSON(REVERSE(FullFilePath), N'\')
  WHERE [key] = @ElementOfInterest - 1;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e0a78e8c000b291a3adedc1929e3081)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution for a complete coverage.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

It is using XML and XQuery for tokenization. No need in any User-Defined-Function (UDF).

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FullFilePath nvarchar(4000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (FullFilePath) VALUES
(N'Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\Oracle\2022-05-04\MSudaitemlov_20220503'),
(N'Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\OracleABC\2022-05-04\FDERDMSudaitemlov_20220503'),
(N'Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\OCSBAGF\2022-05-04\AASSSMSudaitemlov_20220503');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '\'
    , @token int = 8;

SELECT t.* 
    , c.value('(/root/r[sql:variable("@token")]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(FullFilePath, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| ID |                                              FullFilePath                                              | (No column name) |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|  1 | Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\Oracle\2022-05-04\MSudaitemlov_20220503         | Oracle           |
|  2 | Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\OracleABC\2022-05-04\FDERDMSudaitemlov_20220503 | OracleABC        |
|  3 | Y:\dfs-dc-01\Split\Retail\Kroger\Kroger\FTP-FromClient\OCSBAGF\2022-05-04\AASSSMSudaitemlov_20220503   | OCSBAGF          |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Well, you don't "need" a UDF for the JSON solution either, but it sure makes the query tidier (at no performance penalty), so not sure why the need to eliminate it.

Comment: I concur.  XML data model is based on ordered sequences. JSON data model is based on arrays. So they both are a perfect match for such tasks. Though JSON has no real APIs like XPath. XQuery, and XSD validation.