# Get first four comma-separated values in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

If I have a column with 16 comma separated values, I only want to select the first four comma-separated values. I am using an older SQL Server so `string_split` is not an option.

I have an idea how to get the first three values but not four.

Example:

```
f,a,bcd,gd,er,ad,adsadc,asdf,rte,fer,ter,657,4545,sf,ret,tyu
```

Goal: to get

```
f,a,bcd,gd
```

I don't mind keeping the commas in the substring

There is some code online about how to find the first three but I can't necessarily comprehend it.

```
select 
    substring(Column1, 1, charindex(",", Column1, (charindex(",", Column1, (charindex(",", Column1, 1) + 1)) + 1)) - 1)
```

Comment: This is gonna be painful and slow. It's NEVER a good idea to put comma-separated data into a column. The best option here will be to **fix** the schema (because it really is _broken_), probably with an additional table.

Answer (score 0):

In a version that old, your options are pretty limited. Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72144287/20091109):

```
DECLARE @str varchar(255) = 'f,a,bcd,gd,er,ad,adsadc,...,.,,.,.';

SELECT CONCAT(
  c.value('(/x/r[1]/text())[1]', 'sysname'), ',',
  c.value('(/x/r[2]/text())[1]', 'sysname'), ',',
  c.value('(/x/r[3]/text())[1]', 'sysname'), ',',
  c.value('(/x/r[4]/text())[1]', 'sysname')
)
FROM 
(
  SELECT TRY_CONVERT(xml, CONCAT(
    '<x><r><![CDATA[',
    REPLACE(@str, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA['),
    ']]></r></x>'
    )
)) AS t(c);
```

So, you could put this in an inline table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetFirstFourElements
(
  @str varchar(255),
  @sep char(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN (
    SELECT FourElements = CONCAT(
      c.value('(/x/r[1]/text())[1]', 'sysname'), @sep,
      c.value('(/x/r[2]/text())[1]', 'sysname'), @sep,
      c.value('(/x/r[3]/text())[1]', 'sysname'), @sep,
      c.value('(/x/r[4]/text())[1]', 'sysname')
    )
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT TRY_CONVERT(xml, CONCAT(
        '<x><r><![CDATA[',
        REPLACE(@str, @sep, ']]></r><r><![CDATA['),
        ']]></r></x>'
        )
    )) AS t(c)
);
```

And then either call it against a variable:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(255) = 'f,a,bcd,gd,er,ad,adsadc,...,.,,.,.';

SELECT FourElements 
  FROM dbo.GetFirstFourElements(@str, ',') AS f;
```

Or against a table:

```
DECLARE @t table(str varchar(255));

INSERT @t VALUES('a,b,c,d,e,f,g'),
  ('f,a,bcd,gd,er,ad,adsadc,...,.,,.,.');

SELECT t.str, f.FourElements 
  FROM @t AS t
  CROSS APPLY dbo.GetFirstFourElements(t.str, ',') AS f;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bcaRxrXV) (except that is shown in SQL Server 2014, since even they don't support ancient versions of SQL Server anymore).

---

Given the new information ("I can't use user-defined functions, and I don't have any tables"), here's how you can do this from a variable, without a function, and no tables:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(255) = 'f,a,bcd,gd,er,ad,adsadc,...,.,,.,.';

SELECT FourElements = CONCAT(
  c.value('(/x/r[1]/text())[1]', 'sysname'), ',',
  c.value('(/x/r[2]/text())[1]', 'sysname'), ',',
  c.value('(/x/r[3]/text())[1]', 'sysname'), ',',
  c.value('(/x/r[4]/text())[1]', 'sysname')
)
FROM 
(
  SELECT TRY_CONVERT(xml, CONCAT(
    '<x><r><![CDATA[',
    REPLACE(@str, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA['),
    ']]></r></x>'
    )
)) AS t(c);
```

Comment: So Im not able to use any user defined functions or tables, I wanted to just edit what I have above in the question using only substring and charindex etc. I want to eventually use that overall substring in a window function for something else

Comment: @Soaps Why are you not allowed to use functions? Also, your data isn't in tables?