# Select particular value after first space

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table and it has only one column(HID_Value). The value in the column is separated by space . Now all I want is to get the second value after the first Space.

| HID_Value |
| --- |
| AHIT 6 08132022 Exp Reimburse 08/13/2020 0.00 1 |
| APHB 601 08132022 Exp Reimburse 08/13/2020 0.00 1 |
| ATCK 12 08132022 Exp Reimburse 08/13/2020 0.00 1 |
| ARMB 34 08132022 Exp Reimburse 08/13/2020 0.00 1 |
| APLB 5 1 1 5 970515- 900.08000. 144 MS 1 86.88 |
| APLB 5 2 1 5 970515- 900.08000. 144 MS 1 36.25 |
| APLB 5 3 1 5 970515- 900.08000. 144 MS 1 36.25 |

I need the output as below

```
6
601
12
34
5
5
5
```

I tried the below query, but couldn't able to get the expected results.

```sql
select SUBSTRING(HID_Value,5,charindex(' ',HID_Value)+1) from table
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449492/using-t-sql-return-nth-delimited-element-from-a-string) answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

You may use `CHARINDEX` *twice* here, once to find the position of the first space, and the other time to find the position of the second space.  Then, just take a substring of the column value using those two space positions and an offset.

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(HID_Value,
                 CHARINDEX(' ', HID_Value) + 1,
                 CHARINDEX(' ', HID_Value, CHARINDEX(' ', HID_Value) + 1) -
                     CHARINDEX(' ', HID_Value))
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the response @Tim Biegeleisen. But I'm not getting the ouput, Here is the error: 
**Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.**

Comment: Well we _don't_ get this error from your sample data, implying that you have some _other_ data which is causing this.  My guess is that there is one or more `HID_Value` values which do not have three words in them (i.e. at least 2 spaces).  Check your data for this problem.

Comment: @pd  You could add a "Fail-Safe" on the 2nd charindex by simply adding a space  ...   
  HID_Value+' '

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using a bit of JSON

```
Select HID_Value
      ,NewVal = JSON_VALUE('["'+replace(string_escape(HID_Value,'json'),' ','","')+'"]' ,'$[1]')
 From YourTable
```

**Results**

[image]

For something a bit more robust, you can use a `CROSS APPLY`

```
Select A.HID_Value
      ,Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
      ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
      ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
      ,Pos4 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ( '["'+replace(string_escape(HID_Value,'json'),' ','","')+'"]' ) ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

[image]