# Extract data after 2nd last space up to 10 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to extract data after 2nd last space up to 10 characters from a SQL Server column?

Column data is below:

```
INV PNI S000060803 1
INV PNI  P000035365 132
INV PRVC  S000059468 4
INV PIV P000034785 2
INV PIV  T000034785 27
```

Desired result is:

```
S000060803
P000035365
S000059468
P000034785
T000034785
```

Comment: [Using T-SQL, return nth delimited element from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449492/using-t-sql-return-nth-delimited-element-from-a-string)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use syntax working with all versions of SQL Server like this. It's a little bit messy, but should work on any version starting with 2005 at least. I'm using CTE just for demo to create virtual table.

```sql
with tmp as (
    select 'INV PNI S000060803 1' as c
    union all select 'INV PNI  P000035365 132'
    union all select 'INV PRVC  S000059468 4'
    union all select 'INV PIV P000034785 2'
    union all select 'INV PIV  T000034785 27'
)
select SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(c), 0, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(c), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(c)) + 1))), 0, 11)
from tmp
```

Comment: An inferior solution that doesn't work on data as follows: `'INV PIV   T000034785  27'` .

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution based on the `PARSENAME()` function use.

A **minimal reproducible example** is not provided.

An assumption is made that the *tokens* column has just a single space character between words/tokens.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(256));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('INV PNI S000060803 1'),
('INV PNI P000035365 132'),
('INV PRVC S000059468 4'),
('INV PIV P000034785 2'),
('INV PIV T000034785 27');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.* 
    , PARSENAME(c, 2) AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(tokens, SPACE(1), '.')) AS t1(c);
```

**SQL #2**

Implementation when there are multiple spaces between words/tokens.

```
SELECT t.* 
    , PARSENAME(c, 2) AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY  (SELECT TRY_CAST('<r><![CDATA[' + tokens + ']]></r>' AS XML).value('(/r/text())[1] cast as xs:token?','VARCHAR(MAX)')) AS t1(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(x, SPACE(1), '.')) AS t2(c);
```

**Output**

| id | tokens | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INV PNI S000060803 1 | S000060803 |
| 2 | INV PNI P000035365 132 | P000035365 |
| 3 | INV PRVC S000059468 4 | S000059468 |
| 4 | INV PIV P000034785 2 | P000034785 |
| 5 | INV PIV T000034785 27 | T000034785 |

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but here is another option

```
Select A.ID
      ,NewVal = reverse(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]'))
 From  YourTable A
Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape(reverse( YourColumn ),'json'),' ','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

Comment: Please try `'INV PIV   T000034785  27'`.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I have to believe OP's data has the structure/pattern as presented