# Retrieve text between two delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I have text that is formatted in the following naming convention: `ab123_text1_text2_text3_text4_text5_.xlsx`. I am attempting to extract `"**text4**"` block. I have attempted to make use of the `substring` and `charindex` functions.  Also wondering if these results can be duplicated to retrieve **text5** block. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to use the following code to extract the text but I am receiving the "text3" block which is not what I want. Below is the code I am using:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(FILENAME,
                    CHARINDEX('_',FILENAME,CHARINDEX('_',FILENAME) + 1) +1,
                    CHARINDEX('_',FILENAME,CHARINDEX('_',FILENAME,CHARINDEX('_',FILENAME) +1)+1) -
                    CHARINDEX('_',FILENAME,CHARINDEX('_',FILENAME)+1)-1) AS 'SOMETHING'

FROM mytable
```

If the code worked as needed, My results should look like

```
Results Column1:
**Text4** block
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running? This task can be made a lot easier if you can create a new scalar UDF (ideally with `WITH INLINE = ON` too, if supported by your version).

Comment: I am running an old version of SQL... SSMS Version 12

Comment: SSMS is not your SQL Server version - and if you're running SQL Server 2012 you really should update.

Comment: What's the logic how to get exactly this substring? Is this always the part between 4th and 5th occurence of `_`?

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/9bzCfb6y

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using T-SQL, return nth delimited element from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449492/using-t-sql-return-nth-delimited-element-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

If 2016+, you can use a bit of JSON.

If <2016, there is an XML approach as well

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('ab123_text1_text2_text3_text4_text5_.xlsx.')

Select A.SomeCol
     , Pos4 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[4]')
From  @YourTable A
Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([SomeCol],'json'),'_','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol                                     Pos4
ab123_text1_text2_text3_text4_text5_.xlsx.  text4
```

Comment: Even easier with 2022 or Azure where you can add the ordinal position to STRING_SPLIT. `select x.value from @YourTable t 
cross apply string_split(t.SomeCol, '_', 1) x
where x.ordinal = 5`

Comment: @SeanLange Very true.  Never understood why the omitted the ordinal when string_split was introduced  :)

Comment: I couldn't agree more. That was such a massive swing and a miss when that was released.