# Insert XML nodes in order defined by the XML structure

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, nodes

I have a table variable with the folling columns:

```
[ID] TINYINT
[XML] XML
```

The `XML` structure looks like:

```
 <conditions>

    <condition type='expresion'>
        ...
    </condition>
    <condition type='operand'>
        ...
    </condition>
    <condition type='expresion'>
        ...
    </condition>
    <condition type='operand'>
        ...
    </condition>
    <condition type='expresion'>
        ...
    </condition>

</conditions>
```

I need to extract the information above and populate a table with the following sturcuture:

```
[ID]
[ConditionID]
[ConditionXML]
```

where `ConditionID` will be numeric column and `ConditonXML` will be extrated from the original `XML`.

What is very important to me is to generate `ConditionID` values in way to represent the order in the original `XML` structure.

I [have read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17748012/1080354) that this could be done using `ROW_NUMBER` like this:

```
SELECT [ID]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY T.c) AS T
        ,T.c.query('.')
FROM @Test
CROSS APPLY [CondtionsXML].nodes('conditions/condition') T(c)
ORDER BY [ID], T
```

but in the [official documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) is said, that:

> There is no guarantee that the rows returned by a query using
>   ROW_NUMBER() will be ordered exactly the same with each execution
>   unless the following conditions are true:
>
> 1. Values of the partitioned column are unique.
> 2. Values of the ORDER BY columns are unique.
> 3. Combinations of values of the partition column and ORDER BY columns
>      are unique.

and since my `operand` nodes can be the same I am worried I may have some issues. Also, if I remove the `PARTITON BY` clause, the things goes wrong.

Other tenique I could use is to create a separete tale with `INDENTITY` column and insert values into it like this:

```
DECLARE @TEST1 TABLE
(
     [ID] SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,[ParentID] TINYINT
    ,[XML] XML
)

INSERT INTO @TEST1 ([ParentID], [XML])
SELECT [ID]
      ,T.c.query('.')
FROM @Test
CROSS APPLY [CondtionsXML].nodes('conditions/condition') T(c)
```

Could anyone say if this is the way to insert `XML` nodes in a table in the order they are represented in the `XML` structurer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the documentation is wrong and I can not show you some other documentation that backs me up on this.

This is what I think it should be. I emphasized the change.

> There is no guarantee that the rows returned by a query using
>   ROW_NUMBER() will be **numbered** exactly the same with each execution
>   unless **one of** the following conditions are true:

**1. Values of the partitioned column are unique.**

If this condition is true then `row_number()` will return `1` for all rows. It will always do that and nothing can change that behaviour so this condition alone guarantees that the result is the same for every execution.

**2. Values of the ORDER BY columns are unique.**

If values in the order by are unique and you don't have a partition by clause then every value returned by `row_number()` will be unique in the result set and it will always be returned exactly the same for each and every execution of the query.

**3. Combinations of values of the partition column and ORDER BY columns are unique.**

This case is where you have a partition by clause and a order by clause. `row_number()` is starting from one for each partition and if the value used in the order by clause is unique within a partition the numbering will be the same for every execution.

Comment: So, in my case, because my `values` are not unnique even when `partion by clause` is used (as I have said some of the xml nodes are the same)  it won't be correct to use `ROW_NUMBER`. Could you tell if I use the `table with indentity column solution` the stucture order will be preserved?

Comment: Yes it is, but when I use the `cross apply` I am ending with multiple rows with the same `ID` and different `XML`s.

Comment: @gotqn `T.c` is the internal integer representation of the nodes that is shredded by `cross apply`. Then you end up in case **3** above. The combination of the partition column and order by column is unique. It does not matter that the nodes in the XML are identical.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Just being curious, do you know if the table solition will produce the same results?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `(select 1)` construction. It says to sort the result set as is.

```
select [ID]
    , row_number() over (partition by [ID] order by (select 1) ) as T
    , T.c.query('.')
from @Test
cross apply [XML].nodes ('/conditions[1]/condition')T(c)
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you provide a link to documentation, article or something that confirms this?

Comment: I can provide only this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748012/does-the-nodes-method-keep-the-document-order?lq=1

Comment: `select 1` in the order by does not guarantee that the numbers are generated the same for each execution of the query.