# Order of XML nodes from document preserved in insert?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

If I do:

```
INSERT INTO dst
SELECT blah
FROM src
CROSS APPLY xmlcolumn.nodes('blah')
```

where dst has an identity column, can one say for certain that the identity column order matches the order of the nodes from the original xml document?

I think the answer is no, there are no guarantees and that to ensure the ordering is able to be retained, some ordering information needs to also be extracted from the XML at the same time the nodes are enumerated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17764715/1187211

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to see it explicitly in an execution plan, but the `id` column returned by the `nodes()` method is a `varbinary(900)` [*OrdPath*](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/ordpath-ordpath-everywhere/), which does encapsulate the **original xml document order**.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17764715) offered by Mikael Eriksson on the related question [Does the `nodes()` method keep the document order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748012/does-the-nodes-method-keep-the-document-order) relies on the *OrdPath* to provide an `ORDER BY` clause necessary to determine how identity values are assigned for the `INSERT`.

A slightly more compact usage follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #T 
(
    ID integer IDENTITY, 
    Fruit nvarchar(10) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @xml xml = 
    N'
    <Fruits>
      <Apple />
      <Banana />
      <Orange />
      <Pear />
    </Fruits>
    ';

INSERT #T 
    (Fruit)
SELECT 
    N.n.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(10)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('/Fruits/*') AS N (n)
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N.n);

SELECT 
    T.ID, 
    T.Fruit 
FROM #T AS T
ORDER BY
    T.ID;
```

[*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f99b10e26f2eb234f2078344ade5fde1)

Using the *OrdPath* this way is presently undocumented, but the technique is sound in principle:

1. The *OrdPath* reflects document order.
2. The `ROW_NUMBER` computes sequence values ordered by *OrdPath**.
3. The `ORDER BY` clause uses the row number sequence.
4. Identity values are assigned to rows as per the `ORDER BY`.

To be clear, this holds even if parallelism is employed. As Mikael says, the dubious aspect is using `id` in the `ROW_NUMBER` since `id` is not documented to be the *OrdPath*.

---

* The ordering is not shown in plans, but optimizer output using TF 8607 contains:

```
ScaOp_SeqFunc row_number order[CALC:QCOL: XML Reader with XPath filter.id ASC]
```

Answer (score 3):

Under the *current* implementation of `.nodes`, the XML nodes are generated in document order. The result of that is always joined to the original data using a nested loops, which always runs in order also.

Furthermore, inserts are generally serial (except under very specific circumstances that it goes parallel, usually when you have an empty table, and never with an `IDENTITY` value being generated).

Therefore there is no reason why the server would ever return rows in a different order than the document order. You can see from [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a62d36a2952d221427eff848aaffadbb) that that is what happens.

That being said, there is no guarantee that the implementation of `.nodes` won't change, or that inserts may in future go parallel, as neither of these is documented anywhere as being guaranteed. So I wouldn't rely on it without an explicit `ORDER BY`, and you do not have a column to order it on.

> Using an `ORDER BY` would guarantee it. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#limitations-and-restrictions) state: "`INSERT` queries that use `SELECT` with `ORDER BY` to populate rows guarantees how identity values are computed but not the order in which the rows are inserted."

---

Even using `ROW_NUMBER` as some have recommended is also not guaranteed. **The only real solution** is to get the document order directly from XQuery.

The problem is that SQL Server's version of XQuery does not allow using `position(.)` as a result, only as a predicate. Instead, you can use a hack involving the `<<` positional operator.

For example:

```sql
SELECT T.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as RowLabel,
       T.X.value('let $i := . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') as RowNumber
FROM src
CROSS APPLY xmlcolumn.nodes('blah') as T(X);
```

What this does is:

- Assign the current node `.` to the variable `$i`
- Takes all the nodes in `../*` i.e. all children of the parent of this node
- ... `[. << $i]` that are *previous* to `$i`
- and counts them
- Then add 1 to make it one-based