# Generating self-closing xml tags for lists in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, for-xml, select-for-xml

I saw this xml example data in a 2013 SQL Server [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17748012) on Stack Overflow :

```xml
<Fruits>
  <Apple />
  <Banana />
  <Orange />
  <Pear />
</Fruits>
```

I'm more used to seeing such lists structured as (for example):

```xml
<Fruits>
  <Fruit name="Apple" />
  <Fruit name="Banana" />
  <Fruit name="Orange" />
  <Fruit name="Pear" />
</Fruits>
```

I struggled to produce the (textually more compact) self-closing list format using `FOR XML` in SQL Server, eventually settling on:

```sql
SELECT 
    CONVERT(xml, 
        (
            SELECT 
                Apple = '', 
                Banana = '', 
                Orange = '', 
                Pear = ''
            FOR XML RAW ('Fruits'), ELEMENTS
        )
    );
```

Using the `TYPE` directive instead of converting the subquery result to `xml` didn't produce self-closing elements (though the result is logically equivalent):

```xml
<Fruits>
  <Apple></Apple>
  <Banana></Banana>
  <Orange></Orange>
  <Pear></Pear>
</Fruits>
```

Is there a neater way to produce the list in self-closing form using `FOR XML` in SQL Server?

[*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87657e4426167bf15b79bdca818f90f0)

There's no real-world problem to be solved here—I'm simply curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting '' as xml returns a self closing element or query('.') the generated xml, TYPE is required.

```sql
SELECT 
    Apple = '', 
    Banana = cast('' as xml), 
    Orange = '', 
    Pear = cast('' as xml)
FOR XML RAW ('Fruits'), ELEMENTS, TYPE;

SELECT 
(SELECT 
    Apple = '', 
    Banana = '', 
    Orange = '', 
    Pear = ''
FOR XML RAW ('Fruits'), ELEMENTS, TYPE).query('.');
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you *were* actually asking for `FOR XML` to generate self-closing tags, you can get this using `CAST('' AS xml)`

```sql
SELECT 
  Apple = CAST('' AS xml), 
  Banana = CAST('' AS xml), 
  Orange = CAST('' AS xml),
  Pear = CAST('' AS xml)
FOR XML RAW ('Fruits'), ELEMENTS, TYPE;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29abd020088520c3f9419aa4176301bd)

You can also do this using `FOR XML PATH`

```sql
SELECT 
    CAST('' AS xml) Apple, 
    CAST('' AS xml) Banana, 
    CAST('' AS xml) Orange, 
    CAST('' AS xml) Pear
FOR XML PATH('Fruit'), ROOT('Fruits'), TYPE;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c88d4fdb69560a1dd0ad4ac1d8ac3297)

Note that because they are semantically equivalent, any good XML parser will not see a difference, and may freely convert between one and the other without you noticing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer I accepted, I went with:

```sql
DECLARE @x xml = CONVERT(xml, N'');

SELECT 
    Apple = @x, 
    Banana = @x, 
    Orange = @x,
    Pear = @x
FOR XML RAW ('Fruits'), 
    ELEMENTS, 
    TYPE;
```

[image: execution plan]

Tags can be rendered in different ways depending on where and how the rendering is done. This can be in the query processor, specific `FOR XML` server-side code, or even by the client driver in some cases.

Details in [What does server side FOR XML return?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlprogrammability/what-does-server-side-for-xml-return) by the SQL Server Programmability Team.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much the self-closing tags you want, as it is semantically equivalent to a non-self-closing one anyway. It's that you want your data as attributes rather than elements.

It's much easier with `FOR XML PATH`. Normally you would have your date in a table, but I've shown you with a `VALUES` virtual table

```sql
SELECT 
    v.Name AS [@Name]
FROM (VALUES
    ('Apple'), 
    ('Banana'), 
    ('Orange'), 
    ('Pear')
) v(Name)
FOR XML PATH('Fruit'), ROOT('Fruits'), TYPE;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5825e2d26367d98a1cef51a17b54d11)

This does also produce self-closing tags, somewhat as a by-product.